# Dispatching Vuex getter via setInterval

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, html5, timer, vue.js

I am fetching the friend list for a chat application using a Vuex store. I need to dispatch the getter via an interval. Is there a best practices way to do this?

```
<template>
    <aside class="friend-list">
        <h5 class="whos-online">Who's Online</h5>
        <ul class="users">
            <UserListItem v-for="user in friendList" :user="user" :key="user.user_id" />
        </ul>
    </aside>
</template>

<script>
    import UserListItem from './UserListItem'
    import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        name: 'FriendList',

        components: {
            UserListItem,
        },

        created() {
            this.fetchFriendList()
            setInterval(this.fetchFriendList, 3000)
        },

        destroy() {
            clearInterval(this.fetchFriendList)
        },

        methods: {
            fetchFriendList() {
                console.log(this.friendList)
                this.$store.dispatch('chat/fetchFriendList')
            }
        },

        computed: mapGetters({
            friendList: 'chat/friendList'
        }),
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Responding to your question

> Is there a best practices way to [dispatch the getter via an interval]?

You could consider using [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) (read more about using that with `setInterval()` in articles like [this one](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/)) but that might be overkill since you are just updating a list.

Another option to consider is using [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) (presuming your server-side would support it). That way the client-side could be notified of updates to the list instead of having to request them periodically.

### Bug in the sample code

The sample code shows these methods:

> ```
>     created() {
>         this.fetchFriendList()
>         setInterval(this.fetchFriendList, 3000)
>     },
>     destroy() {
>         clearInterval(this.fetchFriendList)
>     },
> ```

However, [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) takes an `intervalID` as a parameter, not a function reference.

> #### Parameters
>
> **`intervalID`**
>   The identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID was returned by the corresponding call to `setInterval()`.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval#Parameters)</sup>

So instead of passing the method reference `this.fetchFriendList`, pass an identifier returned from the call to `setInterval()` in the `created` method.

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval#Parameters</sub>